# Как запустить функцию после перехода на страницу с другой (определенной страницы)

Tags: javascript

В общем у меня есть форма регистрации и когда пользователь нажимает "завершить" его перебрасывает на главную страницу, в этот момент я хочу чтобы сработала функция и открыла форму чтобы человек мог залогиниться.

```
<a href="xxx"><p class="finish-button" id="finish-switch">Finish Registration</p></a>

<script>
//Finish
document.getElementById("finish-switch").addEventListener('click', function(){
            document.getElementById("login-menu-button").click();
});
</script>
```

Проблемма в том что я не знаю как получить данные с какой страницы его перенаправило, так бы я указал что если со страницы регистрации, то запустить функцию. Или может есть другой способ? Подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы можете получить адрес предыдущей страницы при помощи `document.refferer`

```js
    window.onload = function () {
        var a = document.referrer;
        if (a != '') {
            console.log(a); // Тут будет полный путь.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: А возможно как-то указать какую предыдущую кнопку нажимал пользователь?

Comment: @Neia Да, Вы можете эту кнопку передать `get` параметре при переходе на другую страницу. Например, при клике на кнопку менять `href` ссылки и переходить по ней, ну или просто добавить параметр в ссылку.